# Does a remote storage exist for common user accounts (like google/apple) rather than needing my own database?

Tags: database, storage, account

I want to create a website and use a remote database or something similar to allow for cross-device data access for users. So they log on via a computer and see their data, or a phone and see the same data, etc. However, I don't want to start up a business model where I'm incurring costs for a database and charging users a monthly fee or something like that.

Instead, I would like the user themselves to log in via a common account they may have like a google or apple account, and have their own database or storage area through that account that I could use via an API of some sort (ofcourse so long as the user is willing). The closest thing I found was something very specific. It was for google extensions: something called Chrome.storage. This accomplished just what I wanted, except that it only works for extensions and google extensions don't exist on phones. So if I went this route, my website (or actually extension in this case) couldn't save and store data through a phone, which is unacceptable for me.

So I'm back to square one. Basically, my question is: does a common user account like a google or apple or other account also offer a remote storage API that I could use in my website to store and retrieve user data rather than having to setup and use my own remote database?